# Is there an eigenvector based decomposition scheme that will find the longest axis of variation collinear with a named variable?

Tags: pca, multicollinearity, eigenvalues

So far as I understand, algorithms like principal component analysis, spectral decomposition, etc. are similar algorithms that identify orthogonal vectors in a dataset using a different set of heuristics.

For instance, PCA proceeds by identifying the longest axis of variation in the dataset, assigning that to PC1, and then successively assigning the next longest axes of variation that are orthogonal to PC1 to PC2, PC3 ... PCn. After this is done, one can correlate the PC loadings against covariates that are named in one's analysis, and thereby look for collinearity between a given PC and a covariate.

Suppose instead one wants to identify an eigenvector satisfying the following criteria: 1) has collinearity with the named variable that exceeds a specified threshold 2) accounts for more variance than the named variable.

This should enable unique specification of a closely related eigenvector to the named variable; from here, orthogonal vectors could be identified (but for my purposes need not be).

Has such an algorithm been composed?

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  You seem to want to optimise two different things at once.  Does "greatest collinearity" mean highest correlation or highest covariance?

Comment: The "longest axis of variation [with] greatest collinearity" is called the *regression coefficient* (when using ordinary least squares).  A full eigendecomposition is not needed to compute that.  If you want orthogonal vectors, then regress all other variables against that one and perform PCA on their residuals.

Comment: @whuber, as always, thank you for your insightful replies.

i slightly emended my question - for the purposes of this question, the eigenvector should firstly exceed some threshold of collinearity with the named variable, and 2) account for more variance than the named variable.

in other words, I am trying to buy myself a little wiggle room for finding a closely related axis that accounts for more variance than the named variable. does that make sense?